# Formatting input in DataGridView column

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is it possible to make custom input in specific datagridview column using maskeditbox?

I've tried with:

```
private void dgLokacije_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgLokacije.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) 
            {                   
                MaskedTextBox prodCode = e.Control as MaskedTextBox;
                prodCode.Mask = "00000-9999";

            }
        }
```

But than I get error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` On line `prodCode.Mask = "00000-9999";`

Comment: That means `e.Control` is not a `MaskedTextBox`

Comment: [DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox)

Comment: But my datagridview is binded in run-time...

Comment: Not a problem, you just add columns manually and bind your data.

Comment: What I want to do is avoid adding columns manually. I want to use existing column.
I'm wondering is it possible to use TextBox, for example:

if (dgLokacije.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) 
            { 
                TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox; 
                prodCode.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper; 
            }

In this code all characters will be entered in uppercase. So probably it is possible to have custom input maybe using regex... I'm don't have much experience with that...